# MPRemoteCommandCenter playCommand vs togglePlayPauseCommand?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, mpremotecommandcenter

I'm building a iOS media player that plays audio files using the AVPlayer. The player is all working fine. I'm now looking at controlling media playback from the lock screen and from headphones. I have implemented a target for `MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()`'s `playCommand`, `pauseCommand` and `togglePlayPauseCommand` as such:

```
    let commandCenter = MPRemoteCommandCenter.shared()

    commandCenter.pauseCommand.addTarget { (_) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in

        // Pause media

        return .success
    }

    commandCenter.playCommand.addTarget { (_) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in

        // Play media

        return .success
    }
    
    commandCenter.togglePlayPauseCommand.addTarget { (_) -> MPRemoteCommandHandlerStatus in
        
        if player.isPlaying() {
            // Pause media
        } else {
            // Play media 
        }

        return .success
    }
```

After implementing the above, both the lock screen controls and the headphone controls are working fine. **My question is, what is the difference between using playCommand/ pauseCommand vs togglePlayPauseCommand**?

I noticed that on some devices that I test with, the headphones button will not work when I remove the togglePlayPauseCommand. This gives me a hint to what the difference is but I am not sure. Any help clarifying this would be great, thanks!

**UPDATE:**
After some more testing, it seems that `togglePlayPauseCommand` is used to play/pause media for wired headphones. Whereas the separate `playCommand` and `pauseCommand` are used to play/pause media for wireless bluetooth headphones (as well as the lock screen). Still not 100% sure why the two separate methods of playing/pausing media are needed though...

Comment: it's really interesting that the API documentation refers to the same thing for `pauseCommand` & `playCommand` and   `togglePlayPauseCommand`